# pause mpmovieplayer when move to other controller and continue from same point when come back to previous controller ios

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is it possible to pause mpmovieplayer when i move to next page and continue from same point where it was paused when i come back to previous page using mpmovieplayercontroller? 
please help me to resolve.
thanks in advance.

I have tried foll code:- setting up mpmovieplayer

```
 var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
    moviePlayer.view.frame = IBviewVideo!.frame
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
    moviePlayer.contentURL = NSURL(string: "URL")
movieplayer.play()
```

Condition to get time when it was paused in viewwillappear:-

```
if(isPaused){
        let currentTime = Helper.getIntPREF(CURRENT_PLAYBACK_TIME)
        println("playbackTime \(currentTime)")
        moviePlayer!.initialPlaybackTime = NSTimeInterval (currentTime!)
        isPaused = false
        moviePlayer!.play()
    }
```

Can i start playing video from previous time where i have paused?

Comment: Please provide some code sample, tell us what you have tried already

Comment: You can do this using NSUSerDefaults

Comment: @Kelevandos please find updated code

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I have stored time in nsuserdefaults but will I be able to play from same time when return to that page? because i have tried but it starts from 0 not from time where it was paused